# Google Apps Script: trying to read a text file from Google Drive with .getAs(MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm stuck into trouble trying to read an HTML file from a Google Drive. So

I tried :

1. to get a text with a help of `UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://googledrive.com/host/{folderID}/{filename}.html")`, but it fetches some google css file instead of mine.
2. to convert a file from blob to a text string with `file.getAs(MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)`, and it just outputs "Blob" without any file content. How can I extract a file text without any specific libraries?

```
  var dApp = DriveApp;
  var folderIter = dApp.getFoldersByName("Лаборатории ФББ");
  var folder = folderIter.next();
  var filesIter = dApp.getFilesByName("Labs.html");

  var filelist = [];
  var propfiledate = 0;
  var propfilename;

  while(filesIter.hasNext()){

    var file = filesIter.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    var fileurl = file.getUrl();
    var filedate = file.getDateCreated();

    if(filedate >= propfiledate){

      var propfiledate = filedate;
      var propfileurl = fileurl;
      var propfilename = filename;
      var propfile = file;

    }
  }

  Logger.log(propfile);

  // 1st try var myHtmlFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(propfileurl);
  // 2nd try var myHtmlFile = propfile.getAs(MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
  // 3rd try var myHtmlFile = propfile.getBlob().text();
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("test");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  sheet.appendRow(myHtmlFile.toString().split("\n"));

  Logger.log(propfiledate);
  Logger.log(propfilename);
  Logger.log(propfileurl);
}
```

Comment: You understand that the google drive api is a file storage api.  Its not intended for reading the content of files.  You code also appear to be using Google sheets api and not google drive api.

Comment: What is the file you are trying to read? An HTML file?

Comment: Yes, it's an HTML file

Comment: There are some google sheets api code actually. So there is no way to read the content with drive api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Apps Script on a dummy HTML file, you can get the HTML data that is inside of it.

Using DriveApp [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename) method you retrieve the file by the name.

This will return a [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) since there can be many files with similar names.

Then you can get the file blob with [getBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getblob) and the blob data as a string with [getDataAsString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#getdataasstring)

I have managed to get the dummyHTML.html file data by using this previously mentioned methods:

```
function myFunction() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("dummyHTML.html");
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  }
}
```

Comment: It also works for getting the .txt file's content.